# Error Compiling on raspberry Pi - no error details provided in IDE

Tags: arduino-uno

I've just cracked out my Franzis Arduino Tutorial Kit (Best Xmas Present EVER!) and I'm already stuck on my second program.

I successfully wrote and executed a basic 'blink' program, however when I wrote out the second program provided in the manual I get an 'Error Compiling' when trying to check the syntax or run the program.

I tried the obvious of unplugging the board and plugging it back in but this didn't work. When I search for help most forum posts refer to the error message, however I have no message, just the orange warning bar stating 'Error Compiling'

This is the code;

```
// Franzis Arduino
// My second Arduino program

int ledPin = 13; //LED is connected with digital pin 13

// The setup routine configures the digital port
// This routine is executed only once at program start!

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.printIn("Our second Arduino program");
  Serial.printIn();
}

// The main program is an infinate loop
void loop()
{
  Serial.print("5 + 188 yields");
  Serial.print(5+188);
  while(true)
  {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); // Turn on LED
    delay(2000);                 // Wait for a second
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);   // Turn off LED
    delay(2000);                 // Wait for a second
    continue;
  }
}
```

And here's a screenshot of the error message (or lack of);

[image]

Comment: Turn on Verbose Compiling: File->Preferences->Show verbose output. Then, add the output to your question.

Comment: Both check boxes are already ticked, can you explain 'add the output to your question'?

Answer (score 1):

It's not `printIn`, but `println` (as in "print line").

Comment: Thank you for the correction, however my original problem still exists

Comment: You mean, not getting any error message? Try re-installing the IDE.

Comment: Sorry, I did not apply your correction correctly, I used Ln not ln, this is now fixed and running. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Programming code is indeed case-sensitive. It's a lot more strict than a natural language. One missing `;` and all hell breaks lose :-)